# ReactJS keeping a single "Active" state between multiple components

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am attempting to keep with best practices, while adhering to the documentation. Without creating to many one-off methods to handle things for a maintainability standpoint.

Anyway all in all, I am trying to achieve a state between sibling elements that is in sorts an "active" state visually at the least. With something like jQuery I would simply do..

```
$(document).on('.nav-component', 'click', function(e) {
    $('.nav-component').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

However in react, each component in it of itself is independent of the next and previous, and should remain as such per the documents.

That said, when I am handling a click event for a component I can successfully give it a state of active and inactive, toggling it on and off respectively. But I end up in a place where I have multiple "active" elements when I don't need them as such.

This is for setting up a navigation of sorts. So I want the one in use at the moment to have that active class while the rest won't

Answer (score 0):

I use an app.store with reflux to set state for multiple pages/components. You can do the same passing state up to a common component but using the flux pattern is cleaner.

```js
class AppCtrlRender extends Component {
  render() {
  let page = this.state.appState.currentPage;
  let hideAbout = (page != 'about');
  let hideHome = (page != 'home');
  return (
   <div id='AppCtrlSty' style={AppCtrlSty}>
    <div id='allPageSty' style={allPageSty}>
     <AboutPage hide={hideAbout} />
     <HomePage hide={hideHome} />
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

let getState = function() { return {appState: AppStore.getAppState(),}; };

export default class AppCtrl extends AppCtrlRender {
 constructor() {
   super();
  this.state = getState();
 }

 componentDidMount = () => { this.unsubscribe = AppStore.listen(this.storeDidChange); }
 componentWillUnmount = () => { this.unsubscribe(); }
 storeDidChange = () => { this.setState(getState()); }
}
```

In the page/component check for this.props.hide.

```js
export default class AboutPage extends Component {
 render() {
  if (this.props.hide) return null;
  return (
   <div style={AboutPageSty}>
    React 1.4 ReFlux used for app state. This is the About Page.
    <NavMenu />
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: how do you use `class` in JS? does it belong only to ES6?

Comment: Babel is the most popular parser for es6.

Answer (score 0):

Siblings needing to share some sort of state in React is usually a clue that you need to pull state further up the component hierarchy and have a common parent manage it (or pull it out into a state management solution such as Redux).

For sibling components where only one can be active at a time, the key piece of state you need is something which lets you identify which one is currently active and either:

- pass that state to each component as a prop (so the component itself can check if it's currently active - e.g. if each item has an associated id, store the id of the currently active one in a parent component and pass it to each of them as an `activeId` prop)

e.g.:

```
var Nav1 = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {activeId: null}
  },
  handleChange(activeId) {
    this.setState({activeId})
  },
  render() {
    return <div className="Nav">
      {this.props.items.map(item =>
        <NavItem
          activeId={this.state.activeId}
          item={item}
          onClick={this.handleChange}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  }
})
```

- or use it to derive a new prop which is passed to each component (such as an `active` prop to tell each component whether or not it's currently active - e.g. in the id example above, check the id of each component while rendering it: `active={activeId === someObj.id}`)

e.g.:

```
var Nav2 = React.createClass({
  // ... rest as per Nav1...
  render() {
    return <div className="Nav">
      {this.props.items.map(item =>
        <NavItem
          active={this.state.activeId === item.id}
          item={item}
          onClick={this.handleChange}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  }
})
```

The trick with React is to think of your UI in terms of the state you need to render if from scratch (as if you were rendering on the server), instead of thinking in terms of individual DOM changes needed to make the UI reflect state changes (as in your jQuery example), as React handles making those individual DOM changes for you based on complete renderings from two different states.